# Is there a way in flutter to check if the page is opened?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, notifications

I'm working on notifications page and also  badges to show the number of unread notifications on the notifications icon.I want to change the status of notifications to read when the notifications page is opened and update the badges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no, there is away to know if the widget is on the widget tree what means it's opened and maybe not (for example it is down in a column so that means it is still on the widget tree but not infront of the user)

the method can be used in any `StatefulWidget` like this:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (mounted) {
      //do some thing
    }
  }
```

not only in `initState` but almost every where in this `StatefulWidget`.

simply mounted is a Boolean which return true if the widget is in the widget tree and false other wise.

and there are many other ways to check this on state management solutions.

however depending on your use case you don't need that, you can simply reset or hide the notification counter when the notifications screen is opened, by calling a method in `initState()` or `didChangeDependencies()` or even just after the build method which can be done even on `StatelessWidget`, like this:

```
class NotificationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NotificationScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  // this will be called every time you open this widget (screen)

    restNotificationConter();
  return Scaffold(
```

Comment: Thankyou.why didn't i think about this :p .thanks for your time